# How to validate and save JtextField information to a csv file?

Tags: java, swing, validation, csv, jtextfield

I wanted to know how I can validate data in a jtextfield (or if any data is actually entered) then save the validated data to a file in csv format.

Each (more or less) textField has a different data type for example; string, int, double, etc. and I want to see if they meet certain requirements such as length, if they are letters, numbers, contain certain letters or numbers only.

Hope you can help.

Code is in google drive, Click [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B00a7ml5mtDiSzFGT3dJbDk1UkE?usp=sharing)!
Note: It's an eclipse project.

Comment: `"Code is in google drive"` -- Nope, not allowed. Please post any and all pertinent code here as code-formatted text with your question. Please go through the [tour] and the [help] to see other rules/regs and suggestions on how to ask a decent question here.

Comment: Also your question is a two-parter, which is also not good -- understand that this is a question / answer site and not a help site. Please ask one question per post, tell any and all pertinent background information, show your attempt to solve it, and try to be as specific as possible. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Each (more or less) textField has a different data type for example; string, int, double, etc

You can use different components to help with this. For example you might use a JSpinner for numeric values. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more information and examples.

> if they meet certain requirements such as length

For lengths of text you can use a `DocumentFilter` to limit the text. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on Implementing a DocumentFilter that does exactly this.

> contain certain letters or numbers only.

Maybe you can use a `JFormattedTextField`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a Formatted Text Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

I hope you get the idea. Start with the tutorial. Look at the table of contents to see what features are available.